# How to procedurally deform shape of an object?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, displacement

How to procedurally deform shape of an object?
I'm looking for something like [this](https://gyazo.com/6d2062f1f695402a8d1a4bc034680e44) in c4d, is it even possible to make something similar in blender?
Object in gif was created in c4d using noise texture displacement
I believe there're a few ways to make it in blender using curve or displace modifier
As a result I want to deform a bell pepper shape to many many variations procedurally

Bell Pepper model:

[image]

Comment: Please use the tools from this site so that the images are displayed directly as part of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a Displace modifier to the object, set the texture coordinates to "object". Add an empty and set it in the object field. Set the strength to a low value (0.1 for example) and set the direction to "RGB to XYZ".
Add a texture in the modifer, and click on the far right icon of the texture field, alternatively click on the checker icon on the bottom of the properties.

[image]

Set The texture type to clouds, and the color from grayscale to color. Up the size a little bit. (depends on the real scale of your object)

[image]

If your object doesn't deform correctly, you should make sure to have a dense enough mesh. Add a subdivision modifier before the displace modifier and set the divisions to 1 or 2.

Now move your empty object in the scene and the object should deform.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeh, I've already tried it, but it's not really deforming shape of an object, it still looks similar to the default object. I was looking for something similar in the gif I've provided

Comment: Just up the strength of the displace modifier and the scale of the noise scale. I've updated my answer with strength = 2 and noise scale = 5

Comment: Could you please try it with the model I've uploaded?

Comment: What can't you achieve with the workflow I described ?

Comment: It works fine, nvm, I just not satisfied with the way it looks, but that's my model's issue I guess. Thanks a lot, appreciated

Comment: You can test other types of noise instead of clouds if you want another effect.